# URL versioning of images inside css for cache busting

Tags: css, caching, versioning, browser-cache

I have a requirement in my project to version image files which are called from css. I have been researching on 'how to' and found our very own stackoverflow.com is versioning images. I found below code from http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css

```
background-image:url("../Img/sprite-herobox.png?v=d173774f3a9f")
```

Can somebody tell me how it is done?

Comment: Are you using any server side language in the project?

Comment: I suppose this is just a cachebusting technique rather than a versioning information

Comment: @nunopolonia - I am using java. I can put version number inside jsp. But css is static content.

Answer (score 1):

CSS file is not probably a static file but a php/asp file, just with (.css) an extension and css code within

Comment: you can have any extension you want for server side script page, just need to make corresponding changes in the htaccess or other corresponding files